# JTable set cell data type

Tags: jtable, sqldatatypes

When I add data to a JTable from an Oracle database table the data types are according to that of the database (eg NUMBER). However, if I make changes to the cells in the JTable the types automatically become of type String. How can I keep the original type from changing to String when the user edits the field?

Comment: Consider [`DbUtils`](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/apache-commons-dbutils/info), seen [here](http://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&q=%5bjava%5d%20%5bjdbc%5d%20dbutils).

Comment: Which methods exactly? I don't see anything applicable

Comment: Try the [examples](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-dbutils/examples.html).